# opencart - How to change the date format in admin for the product's availability date?

Tags: php, opencart

Instead of year-month-day I want it to show day-month-year.

In:

```
admin\view\template\catalog\product.tpl
```

I replaced all instances of `yy-mm-dd` to `dd-mm-yy` for the javascript code.

In:

```
admin\controller\catalog\product.php
```

I changed `Y-m-d` to `d-m-Y` on line 838 and 840

When I insert a new product, the date display correctly (today's date). But when I click save, it saves it wrong  and it ends up showing 01-01-1970 for all products.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Opencart Version 1.5.2.1.

Thanks,
Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL dates are all saved in the format Y-m-d, and that is what it expects when you enter the date. because you've entered it different to that, it's not understood, and assumed 0 as the value, which gives the epoch time (00:00:00 01-01-1970)

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I figured it out. The problem was that the dates weren't being saved properly in the dabatase. Instead of yyyy-mm-dd I was putting in dd-mm-yyyy. In admin/model/catalog/product.php I've replaced $data['date_available'] with date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['date_available']))

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to change the date *storage* format, as in the examples above. At least in OpenCart ~1.5 you can just change the display date format.

There is one place to change it for the Admin panel, and one place to change it for the public-facing store. For english opencart installations, they are:

```
admin/language/english/english.php
```

and the public date format is in:

```
catalog/language/english/english.php
```

in one or both files change the short date format string to the desired format. E.g. change:

```
$_['date_format_short'] = 'm/d/Y';
```

to `'d/m/Y'` (or vice versa).